# Amplifier circuit for different frequency

Tags: amplifier

I have construct the amplifier circuit by using LT1227 for gain=15. suppose for the input waveform should be amplified to 15 xVin for 0 to 5MHz, but why the output amplitude for higher frequency from2-5Mhz,the output amplitude waveform will decrease? as shown in figure below, the amplitude for input waveform of 1 and 5MHz is about 950mV, but the output amplitude for 1 and 5MHz difference much for the same gain,why are the possible causes of its?

[image: hardware for amplifier]
[image: input waveform for 1MHz]
[image: output waveform for 1MHz]

[image: input waveform for 5M]

[image: output waveform for 5M]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snapshot of your picture with a few brief pointers as to what you might be doing wrong: -

[image]

It's a high speed op-amp and requires basic things to be in place for it to work correctly such as: -

1. Power rail decoupling caps close to the power pins and ceramic. What you have is electrolytics (poor choice unless supplemented by 100nF ceramics) with very long leads making there way to a 0V system that is just not suitable for this type of device. I'm talking about 5mm maximum lengths from pin. via cap to a ground-plane.
2. Same as 1
3. The feedback resistor goes to a breadboard strip that has maybe 3pF capacitance, then links across to the breadboard track that the -Vin pin is connected to - it has maybe another 3pF capacitance to ground. At 5MHz, 6pF has an impedance of about 5 kohms - what value is your feedback resistor? Is it able to counter this 6pF load - maybe a 470R feedback resistor might be just about as high as you'd want to go.
4. Input via a resistor also encounters breadboard capacitance and this will roll-off 5MHz more than 1MHz.
5. What looks like a 100 ohm load resistor goes off to some "0V" point that should, ideally be equipotentially the same as the decoupling capacitor 0Vs. Clearly this is not happening.

This circuit, on a breadboard cannot be expected to work how you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see exactly what your circuit is, but the part is capable of 12 MHz at a gain of 100dB. Given that, I would check your external feedback resistors versus the data sheet recommendations. Plus all the data uses a load of 100 ohms to 1K. What is your load?

Aside from that I recommend using some common techniques for higher frequencies on solderless breadboards. First cut the leads on your resistors so they can either be set vertical in two adjacent holes (or diagonal or 0.3 apart) or cut them and bend so they fit 0.4 to 0.6 spacing. Do the same for jumper wires. In other words, use the shortest possible path. Put a load on the output at the part's output pin and measure from that point.

The breadboards are not great for high frequencies. What is the surface under your breadboard? Each of the rows of holes has a single metal conductor under it. I do this kind of thing on a piece of bare copper PCB with the PCB grounded and all grounds soldered to the PCB. The rest is "up in the air" with wires soldered to the amp pins. It is better than a custom PCB. (I got it from this guy http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/bob-pease-breadboard.htm   Buy the book! If it isn't worth every penny I'll buy it from you and give it to a student.)

Last, have you checked your signal source with a simple load?